# Is there a way for replacing the unspecified text using the command line or simple tools?

Tags: batch-file, replace, ms-word

I am currently writing a simple script that is helpful for my job. Precisely, it should remove the comment's author in the .docx file. I am doing it manually by adjusting the comments.xml file in the \word folder inside the file.
I was thinking a bit about the possible algorithm and came up with the following solution:

1. Extract comments.xml file from .docx.
2. Find and replace the text inside comments.xml.
3. Update comments.xml file with an adjusted version.

Steps 1 and 3 are not too hard, these are simple commands. For example, extraction step can be done like this:

```
 @ECHO OFF
    SET Winrar=C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe
    FOR %%I IN (*.docx) DO (
     "%WinRAR%" e "%%I" word\comments.xml
    )
```

I had a plan to use the Find and Replace (fnr) tool to edit the extracted file.

```
"C:\Comments\fnr.exe" --cl --dir "" --fileMask "*.xml" --find "" --replace ""
```

My problem, however, is in the fact that the author's information is different in different files, so I still have to type in the exact text to be replaced. The line within comments.xml in general looks like this:

```
<w:comment w:id="0" w:author="Author_Name" w:date="YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS" w:initials="AN">
```

and what I'm doing manually is changing `author="Author_Name"` to `author=""`. Is there a way to apply a filter for this edit to be done automatically within the script, please? Thanks in advance!

Edit:
So currently I use a temporary solution that replaces w:author with w:noauthor. LibreOffice and Word cannot properly read the information and indicate "No author" under the comment. The information however is still present in the comments.xml file, I will be really grateful for the advice or solution on how to remove it within the same script. It looks like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET Winrar=C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe
SET fnr=C:\Comments\fnr.exe
FOR %%I IN (*.docx) DO (
 "%WinRAR%" x "%%I" word\comments.xml
 "%fnr%" --cl --dir "C:\Comments\word" --fileMask "*.xml" --find "w:author=" --replace "w:noauthor="
 "%fnr%" --cl --dir "C:\Comments\word" --fileMask "*.xml" --find "w:date=" --replace "w:nodate="
 "%fnr%" --cl --dir "C:\Comments\word" --fileMask "*.xml" --find "w:initials=" --replace "w:noinitials="
 "%WinRAR%" u "%%I" word\
 del C:\Comments\word\ /q
)
```

Comment: Doesn't fnr allow .NET regex matching with the --useRegex option? e.g. something like 
--useRegex --find "w:Author\".+?\""

Comment: It actually works great! I am slightly stuck on how exactly to make it change as I want it though. `--useRegex --find "w:author=\".+?\"" --replace "w:author="""` - this command changes the text `w:author="Author_Name"` to `w:author="`, and, since the quote is not closed, the document crashes on attempt to open it. Should I write it in a way like `--replace "w:author=+"+"+ "`?

Comment: `--useRegex --find "w:author=\".+?\"" --replace "w:author=\"\"` - this worked flawlessly. Thank you a million, you are my hero! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution looks like this:

```
   @ECHO OFF
SET Winrar=C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe
SET fnr=C:\Comments\fnr.exe
FOR %%I IN (*.docx) DO (
 "%WinRAR%" x "%%I" word\comments.xml
 "%fnr%" --cl --dir "C:\Comments\word" --fileMask "*.xml" --useRegex --find "w:author=\".+?\"" --replace "w:author=\"\"
 "%fnr%" --cl --dir "C:\Comments\word" --fileMask "*.xml" --useRegex --find "w:date=\".+?\"" --replace "w:date=\"\"
 "%fnr%" --cl --dir "C:\Comments\word" --fileMask "*.xml" --useRegex --find "w:initials=\".+?\"" --replace "w:initials=\"\"
 "%WinRAR%" u "%%I" word\
 del C:\Comments\word\ /q
)
```

Comment: In this forum, this should be posted as an edit to your question, rather than an answer.

Comment: Thank you, I will pay attention next time for sure.